# Is new[] faster than Win32's VirtualAlloc?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management

I was testing the performance of some string pool allocators: I considered the one presented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx) that calls `Virtual­Alloc` and then carves out sub-allocations, and a similar implementation using standard C++ (without directly calling any Win32 API) and `new[]`.

I expected the `Virtual­Alloc` version to be faster, since I thought there should be less overhead than C++ `new[]`; but the results I observed are the opposite: using `new[]` seems to result in faster code than using the lower-level `Virtual­Alloc`.

I ran the test several times (the code is compiled with VS2010 SP1), and the output is something like this:

> ```
> String pool using VirtualAlloc: 1280.07 ms
> String pool using new[]: 799.193 ms
> ```

Why is this? Why does `new[]` seem to be faster than `VirtualAlloc`?

Test source code follows:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Testing VirtualAlloc vs. new[].
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// String pool allocator using VirtualAlloc, based on this:
// http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc
{
public:

    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc()
        : m_pchNext(nullptr), 
          m_pchLimit(nullptr), 
          m_phdrCur(nullptr)
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        m_dwGranularity = static_cast<DWORD>( 
            RoundUp( sizeof(HEADER) + MIN_CBCHUNK, si.dwAllocationGranularity 
            ));
    }

    ~StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc()
    {
        HEADER* phdr = m_phdrCur;
        while (phdr) 
        {
            HEADER * phdrPrev = phdr->m_phdrPrev;
            VirtualFree(phdr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            phdr = phdrPrev;
        }
    }

    wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        return AllocString(source.c_str(), source.c_str() + source.length());
    }

private:
    union HEADER 
    {
        struct 
        {
            HEADER* m_phdrPrev;
            SIZE_T  m_cb;
        };
        wchar_t alignment;
    };

    enum 
    { 
        MIN_CBCHUNK = 32000,
        MAX_CHARALLOC = 1024*1024
    };

    wchar_t*  m_pchNext;
    wchar_t*  m_pchLimit;
    HEADER*   m_phdrCur;
    DWORD     m_dwGranularity;

    static SIZE_T RoundUp(SIZE_T cb, SIZE_T units)
    {
        return ((cb + units - 1) / units) * units;
    }

    wchar_t* AllocString(const wchar_t* pchBegin, const wchar_t* pchEnd)
    {
        SIZE_T cchTotal = pchEnd - pchBegin + 1;
        if (cchTotal > MAX_CHARALLOC) 
            throw length_error("String too big.");

        wchar_t* psz = m_pchNext;
        if (m_pchNext + cchTotal <= m_pchLimit) 
        {
            m_pchNext += cchTotal;
            lstrcpynW(psz, pchBegin, static_cast<int>(cchTotal));
            return psz;
        }

        SIZE_T cbAlloc = RoundUp(cchTotal * sizeof(wchar_t) + sizeof(HEADER), m_dwGranularity);
        BYTE* pbNext = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(
            VirtualAlloc(nullptr, cbAlloc, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
        if (pbNext == nullptr) 
            throw bad_alloc();

        m_pchLimit = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(pbNext + cbAlloc);
        HEADER* phdrCur = reinterpret_cast<HEADER*>(pbNext);
        phdrCur->m_phdrPrev = m_phdrCur;
        phdrCur->m_cb = cbAlloc;
        m_phdrCur = phdrCur;
        m_pchNext = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(phdrCur + 1);
        return AllocString(pchBegin, pchEnd);
    }

    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc(const StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc &);
    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc & operator=(const StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc &);
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// String pool allocator that uses standard C++ (no Win32 stuff) and new[].
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolUsingNew
{
public:

    StringPoolUsingNew()
        : m_pchNext(NULL), 
          m_pchLimit(NULL), 
          m_currChunk(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~StringPoolUsingNew()
    {
        for (auto it = m_chunks.begin(); it != m_chunks.end(); ++it)
            delete *it;
    }

    wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        return AllocString(source.c_str(), source.c_str() + source.length());
    }

private:

    class Chunk
    {
    public:
        explicit Chunk(size_t maxCharCount)
        {
            m_data = new wchar_t[maxCharCount];
            m_maxCharCount = maxCharCount;
        }

        ~Chunk()
        {
            delete [] m_data;
        }

        wchar_t* Begin()             { return m_data; }
        const wchar_t* Begin() const { return m_data; }
        size_t Length() const        { return m_maxCharCount; }

    private:
        Chunk(const Chunk&);
        Chunk& operator=(const Chunk&);

        wchar_t * m_data;
        size_t m_maxCharCount;
    };

    static const size_t kMinChunkCharCount = 16000;
    static const size_t kMaxCharAlloc = 1024*1024;

    wchar_t*  m_pchNext;
    wchar_t*  m_pchLimit;
    Chunk*    m_currChunk;
    vector<Chunk*> m_chunks;

    wchar_t* AllocString(const wchar_t* pchBegin, const wchar_t* pchEnd)
    {
        const size_t cchTotal = pchEnd - pchBegin + 1;
        if (cchTotal > kMaxCharAlloc) 
            throw length_error("String too big.");

        wchar_t* dest = m_pchNext;
        if (m_pchNext + cchTotal <= m_pchLimit) 
        {
            m_pchNext += cchTotal;
            const size_t copyCount = cchTotal - 1;
            if (copyCount != 0)
                wmemcpy(dest, pchBegin, copyCount);
            dest[copyCount] = L'\0';
            return dest;
        }

        const size_t newChunkSize = max(cchTotal, kMinChunkCharCount);
        Chunk* newChunk = new Chunk(newChunkSize);
        m_chunks.push_back(newChunk);

        m_pchNext = newChunk->Begin();
        m_pchLimit = newChunk->Begin() + newChunk->Length();
        m_currChunk = newChunk;

        return AllocString(pchBegin, pchEnd);
    }

    StringPoolUsingNew(const StringPoolUsingNew&);
    StringPoolUsingNew& operator=(const StringPoolUsingNew&);
};


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Perf Measurement
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

long long Counter() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

long long Frequency() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

void PrintTime(long long start, long long finish, const char * s) 
{
    cout << s << ": " << (finish - start) * 1000.0 / Frequency() << " ms" << endl;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Test
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    static const int kExitOk = 0;
    static const int kExitError = 1;
    try
    {
        long long start = 0;
        long long finish = 0;

        const auto shuffled = []() -> vector<wstring> 
        {
            const wstring lorem[] = {
                L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                L"Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed",
                L"pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,",
                L"sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",
                L"Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.",
                L"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et",
                L"malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.",
                L"Mauris et orci."
            };

            vector<wstring> v;
            for (long long i = 0; i < 400*1000; ++i) 
            {
                for (auto it = begin(lorem); it != end(lorem); ++it) 
                {
                    v.push_back((*it) + L" (#" + to_wstring(i) + L")");
                }
            }
            random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

            return v;
        }();

        start = Counter();
        {
            StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc pool;
            vector<const wchar_t*> v;
            for (auto it = shuffled.begin(); it != shuffled.end(); ++it)
            {
                v.push_back( pool.DuplicateString(*it) );
            }
        }
        finish = Counter();
        PrintTime(start, finish, "String pool using VirtualAlloc");

        start = Counter();
        {
            StringPoolUsingNew pool;
            vector<const wchar_t*> v;
            for (auto it = shuffled.begin(); it != shuffled.end(); ++it)
            {
                v.push_back( pool.DuplicateString(*it) );
            }
        }
        finish = Counter();
        PrintTime(start, finish, "String pool using new[]");

        return kExitOk;
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "*** ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;
        return kExitError;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: You're also using the CRT-sub-allocator when using `operator new[]`, aren't you? I.e, I'd be interested in seeing where doing *none* of the above and just using `new` fell into your findings.

Comment: At the bottom of it all, they're all going to end up calling VirtualAlloc (if they run on Windows, anyway). The primary question is how *often* they call it. Allocating more memory at a time, so you call VirtualAlloc less often will usually improve speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, [@JamesMcNellis found the main problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15036937/1629821), i.e. the fact that `lstrcpynW` was used in the `VirtualAlloc`-based pool allocator, instead `wmemcpy` was used in the `new[]`-based pool allocator.

I modified the original code, uniformly using `wmemcpy`, and running the tests several times and calculating the average execution time for each test (excluding the first run).

I also added an `HeapAlloc`-based pool allocator and a simple `vector<wstring>` to the benchmarks.

Now the results are:

> ```
> --- Tests summary ---
> VirtualAlloc : 781.671 ms
> HeapAlloc    : 806.597 ms
> new[]        : 889.792 ms
> STL strings  : 1491.36 ms
> ```

So, **`VirtualAlloc`** seems to be the fastest one (as expected).

Compilable code follows (built with VS2010 SP1 / VC10):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Testing VirtualAlloc vs. HeapAlloc vs. new[] vs. STL strings.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// String pool allocator using VirtualAlloc, based on this:
// http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc
{
public:

    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc()
        : m_pchNext(nullptr), 
        m_pchLimit(nullptr), 
        m_phdrCur(nullptr)
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        m_dwGranularity = static_cast<DWORD>( 
            RoundUp( sizeof(HEADER) + MIN_CBCHUNK, si.dwAllocationGranularity 
            ));
    }

    ~StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc()
    {
        HEADER* phdr = m_phdrCur;
        while (phdr) 
        {
            HEADER * phdrPrev = phdr->m_phdrPrev;
            VirtualFree(phdr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
            phdr = phdrPrev;
        }
    }

    const wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        return AllocString(source.c_str(), source.c_str() + source.length());
    }

private:
    union HEADER 
    {
        struct 
        {
            HEADER* m_phdrPrev;
            SIZE_T  m_cb;
        };
        wchar_t alignment;
    };

    enum 
    { 
        MIN_CBCHUNK = 32000,
        MAX_CHARALLOC = 1024*1024
    };

    wchar_t*  m_pchNext;
    wchar_t*  m_pchLimit;
    HEADER*   m_phdrCur;
    DWORD     m_dwGranularity;

    static SIZE_T RoundUp(SIZE_T cb, SIZE_T units)
    {
        return ((cb + units - 1) / units) * units;
    }

    wchar_t* AllocString(const wchar_t* pchBegin, const wchar_t* pchEnd)
    {
        SIZE_T cchTotal = pchEnd - pchBegin + 1;
        if (cchTotal > MAX_CHARALLOC) 
            throw length_error("String too big.");

        wchar_t* psz = m_pchNext;
        if (m_pchNext + cchTotal <= m_pchLimit) 
        {
            m_pchNext += cchTotal;
            wmemcpy(psz, pchBegin, cchTotal);
            return psz;
        }

        SIZE_T cbAlloc = RoundUp(cchTotal * sizeof(wchar_t) + sizeof(HEADER), m_dwGranularity);
        BYTE* pbNext = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(
            VirtualAlloc(nullptr, cbAlloc, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
        if (pbNext == nullptr) 
            throw bad_alloc();

        m_pchLimit = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(pbNext + cbAlloc);
        HEADER* phdrCur = reinterpret_cast<HEADER*>(pbNext);
        phdrCur->m_phdrPrev = m_phdrCur;
        phdrCur->m_cb = cbAlloc;
        m_phdrCur = phdrCur;
        m_pchNext = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(phdrCur + 1);
        return AllocString(pchBegin, pchEnd);
    }

    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc(const StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc &);
    StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc & operator=(const StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc &);
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// String pool allocator using HeapAlloc, 
// based on the VirtualAlloc allocator.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc
{
public:

    StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc()
        : m_pchNext(nullptr), 
        m_pchLimit(nullptr), 
        m_phdrCur(nullptr)
    {
        m_heap = HeapCreate(0, 0, 0);
        if (m_heap == nullptr)
            throw runtime_error("Can't create an heap with HeapCreate().");

        SYSTEM_INFO si;
        GetSystemInfo(&si);
        m_dwGranularity = static_cast<DWORD>( 
            RoundUp( sizeof(HEADER) + MIN_CBCHUNK, si.dwAllocationGranularity 
            ));
    }

    ~StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc()
    {
        HEADER* phdr = m_phdrCur;
        while (phdr) 
        {
            HEADER * phdrPrev = phdr->m_phdrPrev;
            HeapFree(m_heap, 0, phdr);
            phdr = phdrPrev;
        }
        HeapDestroy(m_heap);
    }

    const wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        return AllocString(source.c_str(), source.c_str() + source.length());
    }

private:
    union HEADER 
    {
        struct 
        {
            HEADER* m_phdrPrev;
            SIZE_T  m_cb;
        };
        wchar_t alignment;
    };

    enum 
    { 
        MIN_CBCHUNK = 32000,
        MAX_CHARALLOC = 1024*1024
    };

    HANDLE    m_heap;
    wchar_t*  m_pchNext;
    wchar_t*  m_pchLimit;
    HEADER*   m_phdrCur;
    DWORD     m_dwGranularity;

    static SIZE_T RoundUp(SIZE_T cb, SIZE_T units)
    {
        return ((cb + units - 1) / units) * units;
    }

    wchar_t* AllocString(const wchar_t* pchBegin, const wchar_t* pchEnd)
    {
        SIZE_T cchTotal = pchEnd - pchBegin + 1;
        if (cchTotal > MAX_CHARALLOC) 
            throw length_error("String too big.");

        wchar_t* psz = m_pchNext;
        if (m_pchNext + cchTotal <= m_pchLimit) 
        {
            m_pchNext += cchTotal;
            wmemcpy(psz, pchBegin, cchTotal);
            return psz;
        }

        SIZE_T cbAlloc = RoundUp(cchTotal * sizeof(wchar_t) + sizeof(HEADER), m_dwGranularity);
        BYTE* pbNext = static_cast<BYTE*>( HeapAlloc(m_heap, 0, cbAlloc) );
        if (pbNext == nullptr) 
            throw bad_alloc();

        m_pchLimit = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(pbNext + cbAlloc);
        HEADER* phdrCur = reinterpret_cast<HEADER*>(pbNext);
        phdrCur->m_phdrPrev = m_phdrCur;
        phdrCur->m_cb = cbAlloc;
        m_phdrCur = phdrCur;
        m_pchNext = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(phdrCur + 1);
        return AllocString(pchBegin, pchEnd);
    }

    StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc(const StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc &);
    StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc & operator=(const StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc &);
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// String pool allocator that uses standard C++ (no Win32 stuff) and new[].
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolUsingNew
{
public:

    StringPoolUsingNew()
        : m_pchNext(NULL), 
        m_pchLimit(NULL), 
        m_currChunk(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~StringPoolUsingNew()
    {
        for (auto it = m_chunks.begin(); it != m_chunks.end(); ++it)
            delete *it;
    }

    const wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        return AllocString(source.c_str(), source.c_str() + source.length());
    }

private:

    class Chunk
    {
    public:
        explicit Chunk(size_t maxCharCount)
        {
            m_data = new wchar_t[maxCharCount];
            m_maxCharCount = maxCharCount;
        }

        ~Chunk()
        {
            delete [] m_data;
        }

        wchar_t* Begin()             { return m_data; }
        const wchar_t* Begin() const { return m_data; }
        size_t Length() const        { return m_maxCharCount; }

    private:
        Chunk(const Chunk&);
        Chunk& operator=(const Chunk&);

        wchar_t * m_data;
        size_t m_maxCharCount;
    };

    static const size_t kMinChunkCharCount = 16000;
    static const size_t kMaxCharAlloc = 1024*1024;

    wchar_t*  m_pchNext;
    wchar_t*  m_pchLimit;
    Chunk*    m_currChunk;
    vector<Chunk*> m_chunks;

    wchar_t* AllocString(const wchar_t* pchBegin, const wchar_t* pchEnd)
    {
        const size_t cchTotal = pchEnd - pchBegin + 1;
        if (cchTotal > kMaxCharAlloc) 
            throw length_error("String too big.");

        wchar_t* dest = m_pchNext;
        if (m_pchNext + cchTotal <= m_pchLimit) 
        {
            m_pchNext += cchTotal;
            const size_t copyCount = cchTotal - 1;
            if (copyCount != 0)
                wmemcpy(dest, pchBegin, copyCount);
            dest[copyCount] = L'\0';
            return dest;
        }

        const size_t newChunkSize = max(cchTotal, kMinChunkCharCount);
        Chunk* newChunk = new Chunk(newChunkSize);
        m_chunks.push_back(newChunk);

        m_pchNext = newChunk->Begin();
        m_pchLimit = newChunk->Begin() + newChunk->Length();
        m_currChunk = newChunk;

        return AllocString(pchBegin, pchEnd);
    }

    StringPoolUsingNew(const StringPoolUsingNew&);
    StringPoolUsingNew& operator=(const StringPoolUsingNew&);
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is just a simple vector<wstring>, to compare performance of this 
// simple and easy approach vs. the other pool allocators.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
class StringPoolVectorOfString
{
public:

    StringPoolVectorOfString()
    {
    }

    ~StringPoolVectorOfString()
    {
    }

    const wchar_t* DuplicateString(const wstring& source)
    {
        m_strings.push_back(source);
        return m_strings.back().c_str();
    }

private:
    // Simplest case: a STL vector of STL strings
    vector<wstring> m_strings;

    StringPoolVectorOfString(const StringPoolVectorOfString&);
    StringPoolVectorOfString& operator=(const StringPoolVectorOfString&);
};


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                          Perf Measurement
//------------------------------------------------------------------------

long long Counter() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}

long long Frequency() 
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
    return li.QuadPart;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Tests
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Prints the first N strings in a vector-like container.
template <typename Container>
void PrintFirst(const Container & c, const size_t firstN)
{
    const size_t n = min(firstN, c.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        wcout << "#" << (i+1) << ": " << c[i] << '\n';
    wcout << endl;
}

// Prints the first N strings using the specified allocator.
template <typename Allocator>
void VerifyAllocator(const vector<wstring>& source, const size_t firstN, const char* allocatorName)
{
    const size_t n = min(firstN, source.size());

    Allocator alloc;
    vector<const wchar_t*> v;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        v.push_back( alloc.DuplicateString(source[i]) );
    }

    wcout << allocatorName << " :\n";
    PrintFirst(v, n);
}

// Tests a given allocator, returning the execution time in ms.
template <typename Allocator>
double TestAllocator(const vector<wstring>& source, const char* allocatorName)
{
    wcout << "Testing " << allocatorName << " : ";
    long long start = Counter();
    {
        Allocator alloc;
        vector<const wchar_t*> v;

        for (auto it = source.begin(); it != source.end(); ++it)
        {
            v.push_back( alloc.DuplicateString(*it) );
        }
    }
    long long finish = Counter();
    const double time = (finish - start) * 1000.0 / Frequency(); // ms

    wcout << time << " ms\n";
    return time;
}

// Calculates the average in a vector of doubles.
double Average(const vector<double>& data)
{
    if (data.empty())
        throw invalid_argument("Can't compute average of empty vector.");

    double sum = data[0];
    const size_t count = data.size();
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
        sum += data[i];
    }
    return (sum / count);
}

// App entry-point ("test driver").
int main()
{
    static const int kExitOk = 0;
    static const int kExitError = 1;
    try
    {
        wcout << '\n';
        wcout << "Testing VirtualAlloc vs. HeapAlloc vs. new[] allocators vs STL strings.\n";
        wcout << "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n"; 

        wcout << "Preparing some strings for testing...\n";

        const auto shuffled = []() -> vector<wstring> 
        {
            const wstring lorem[] = {
                L"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.",
                L"Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed",
                L"pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero,",
                L"sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.",
                L"Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.",
                L"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et",
                L"malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede.",
                L"Mauris et orci."
            };

            vector<wstring> v;
#ifdef _DEBUG
            static const int kLoopCount = 10;
#else
            static const int kLoopCount = 400*1000;
#endif
            for (long long i = 0; i < kLoopCount; ++i) 
            {
                for (auto it = begin(lorem); it != end(lorem); ++it) 
                {
                    v.push_back((*it) + L" (#" + to_wstring(i) + L")");
                }
            }
            random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

            return v;
        }();

        wcout << "Total string count: " << shuffled.size() << "\n\n";
        wcout << "Some verification output ...\n\n";
        wcout << "Original array of strings :\n";
        PrintFirst(shuffled, 5);

        VerifyAllocator<StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc>(shuffled, 5, "VirtualAlloc");
        VerifyAllocator<StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc>(shuffled, 5, "HeapAlloc");
        VerifyAllocator<StringPoolUsingNew>(shuffled, 5, "new[]");
        VerifyAllocator<StringPoolVectorOfString>(shuffled, 5, "vector<wstring>");

        vector<double> timeVirtualAlloc;
        vector<double> timeHeapAlloc;
        vector<double> timeNew;
        vector<double> timeStlString;

        static const int kTestCount = 10;

        // First execution tests are discarded.
        wcout << "\nWarm up... discard first tests execution.\n";
        TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc>(shuffled, "VirtualAlloc");
        TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc>(shuffled, "HeapAlloc");
        TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingNew>(shuffled, "new[]");
        TestAllocator<StringPoolVectorOfString>(shuffled, "vector<wstring>");

        // Run the tests several times and compute the average for each test.
        for (int i = 0; i < kTestCount; i++)
        {
            wcout << "\nTest loop #" << (i+1) << ":\n";
            timeVirtualAlloc.push_back( TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingVirtualAlloc>(shuffled, "VirtualAlloc") );
            timeHeapAlloc.push_back( TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingHeapAlloc>(shuffled, "HeapAlloc") );
            timeNew.push_back( TestAllocator<StringPoolUsingNew>(shuffled, "new[]") );
            timeStlString.push_back( TestAllocator<StringPoolVectorOfString>(shuffled, "vector<wstring>") );
        }

        // Print average times
        wcout << "\n\n--- Tests summary ---\n";
        wcout << "VirtualAlloc : " << Average(timeVirtualAlloc) << " ms\n";
        wcout << "HeapAlloc    : " << Average(timeHeapAlloc) << " ms\n";
        wcout << "new[]        : " << Average(timeNew) << " ms\n";
        wcout << "STL strings  : " << Average(timeStlString) << " ms\n";
        wcout << '\n';

        return kExitOk;
    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        wcerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return kExitError;
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 17):

Yes, calling `new[]` repeatedly is much faster than calling `VirtualAlloc` repeatedly.

First, it is important to understand what `new T[N]` does.  The `new` operator allocates storage by calling `operator new[]`.  At least since Visual C++ 2010, `operator new[]` simply calls `malloc`, which calls the Windows API [`HeapAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597.aspx) to allocate storage from the CRT heap.  Prior to Visual C++ 2012, each CRT has its own heap, created via [`HeapCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599.aspx).  In Visual C++ 2012, the CRT uses the process heap, obtained via [`GetProcessHeap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569.aspx).  From a performance standpoint, it doesn't matter which heap is used.

[`VirtualAlloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887.aspx) is used to map pages of memory into the virtual address space of a process.  This function is used when you need control over whole pages.  For example, if you want to allocate storage to hold executable code, you need to use `VirtualAlloc` so that you can change the permissions on that storage to allow execution.  `VirtualAlloc` is not optimized for general purpose memory allocation.

For that, you need a heap, which maps a large region of address space at a time, then services allocation requests from that mapped address space.  A heap does not have to map and unmap virtual pages every time an allocation is requested (and, also importantly, a heap does not have to zero memory every time an allocation is performed).

When I run your original benchmark, I get the following result:

```
String pool using VirtualAlloc: 1162.45 ms
String pool using new[]: 625.842 ms
```

I replaced your usage of `VirtualAlloc` with `HeapAlloc`.  To do this, I created a private heap for the allocator using `HeapCreate(0, 0, 0)`, then replaced the calls to `VirtualAlloc` and `VirtualFree` with calls to `HeapAlloc` and `HeapFree` from this private heap.  (Note that I did not use the process heap, because as I explained above, `new[]` uses that heap, so using that heap also here could change the performance of the `new[]` allocator.)  The results of my modified allocator are as follows:

```
String pool using HeapAlloc: 919.853 ms
String pool using new[]: 636.515 ms
```

Well, that's extremely disappointing!  We improved the performance of the custom allocator by 21%, but it's still much slower than `new[]`.  What's up with that?

The profiler helpfully pointed out what the problem is:  your benchmark is comparing apples and oranges.  Your `new[]`-based allocator uses `wmemcpy` to copy strings, but your `VirtualAlloc`-based allocator uses `lstrcpyn`.  `wmemcpy` simply calls `memcpy`, which has an intrinsic form, so it can be fully inlined with the insanely fast intrinsic form.  `lstrcpyn` is a Windows API function that cannot be inlined.  Your `VirtualAlloc`-based allocator doesn't stand a chance!

I replaced the use of `lstrcpyn` with `wmemcpy`.  The results are as follows:

```
String pool using HeapAlloc: 636.149 ms
String pool using new[]: 655.479 ms
```

And these are the results that we expect:  they perform roughly the same, with `new[]` being just a little bit slower, probably because of the small overhead of calling through `operator new` and `malloc`.

Comment: Two notes:  [1] I used Visual C++ 2012, but I would expect the same results with Visual C++ 2010.  [2] I actually ran your benchmark 11 times for each test, discarded the first run, then averaged the rest of the runs to present the results here, to eliminate noise in the results (there wasn't much difference between runs, but I wanted to be sure).

Comment: I also replaced the use of `lstrcpyn` with `wmemcpy` in the `VirtualAlloc` allocator, compiled the code using VC10 (VS2010 SP1), and after running some tests (discarding the first results) and getting the average, `VirtualAlloc` took 760 ms vs. `new[]` 798 ms. So `VirtualAlloc` seemed a bit faster than `new[]` as well.

Comment: I adjusted the code using your excellent point on `wmemcpy`, and [`VirtualAlloc` seems to be fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15142370/1629821) (as I expected).

Answer (score 7):

Because `new` will make one call to `VirtualAlloc` (or, more likely, `HeapAlloc`) for quite a bit of memory at once, then use that for several of your calls to `new`, where a call `VirtualAlloc` will do exactly what you asked for, alloocate precisely what you asked for. Equally when releasing memory with `delete` it is faster than `VirtualFree`, because larger lots of memory is freed at once.

It's exactly the same as using `fgetc` is faster than `ReadFile` - sure, if you read one gigabyte at once, `ReadFile` is probably a fair bit faster tan calling `fgetc` a gazillion times, but if you read one byte at a time, `ReadFile` will be much heaver on the system than using `fgetc`, which will read several (probably 4KB) of data in one go, and then dole out a character at a time from that buffer until it's empty.

Comment: +1. ReadFile and fstreams both buffer (by default, anyway, assuming your hFile was opened with buffering enabled), but an `fgetc()` call can easily be inlined, whereas that API invoke for ReadFile... ouch.

Comment: Yes, of course, the OS will also buffer, but you have to call across into the Kernel to get to the buffer, whereas the C library has the buffer "easily reached" [quite possibly inlined inside fgetc() or somewhere close].

Comment: Exaclty. That trip through the ReadFile API is hideous, especially compared to what will ultimately be just a pointer increment and a `ret` for an inlined-`fgetc()` the vast majority of the time.

Comment: I think `new` calls `malloc` calls `HeapAlloc`. So does `HeapAlloc` make one call to `VirtualAlloc` for quite a bit of memory at once, than use that for several calls?

Comment: So, the exact details of how `new` and `malloc` works and how `HeapAlloc` is related to them is a little beyond my knowledge, as I haven't looked closely at MS code for about 5-6 years now. I've written some small programs to do simple things like read files and such, but when I was working on driver code in Windows was more than 5 years back. But as a principle, both `new` and `malloc` are optimized for small to medium size allocations. `HeapAlloc` is called to get a large chunk of memory, and it probably calls a function that is shared between `VirtualAlloc` and `HeapAlloc` somwehere inside

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I tried modifying a bit the test, increasing the chunk size for the `VirtualAlloc` allocator, making it 10MB; but the `new[]`-based allocator is still faster.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible that VirtualAlloc is never faster than new - when I said new is optimized for small allocations, I didn't say it's not going to do well in a large allocation. VirtualAlloc is always calling into the OS, it takes 5 parameters, and it's really flexible - meaning a lot of if-statements inside the function. The more I think about it, the more I believe that you never see VirtualAlloc in the chain of calls that form `new`. Since this is clearly a "XY question", what are you actually trying to do - or are you just thinking that calling the OS is faster for some reason?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I believe that `new` calls `malloc` calls `HeapAlloc`, and I imagined that `HeapAlloc` called `VirtualAlloc` (but I'm not sure about this last "call chain"). I thought that the CRT could introduce some overhead if compared to raw Win32 `VirtualAlloc` API calls. I was trying to speed up memory allocations. Thanks.

Comment: Use "new" and "delete". It's portable, and if you are getting performance problems, bulk allocate a block of objects!

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes, that is what I discovered with this test ("_When in doubt, measure._"), but this is not what I expected at first.

Comment: Sure, that sort of thing happens from time to time, you think you know which gives best performance, but it doesn't match what you think.

Comment: Actually, [`VirtualAlloc` is the fastest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15142370/1629821).